# Do we have two definitions for conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability

I have currently two probability books in front of me, and the more I read about conditional probabilities, the more I get confused.

My first question is: do we have two definitions for conditional probabilities?
I mean, are these two definitions valid for conditional probabilities? given that $P(Y\in B)$ and $P(Y=y)$ will not equal 0.

$P(X\in A|Y=y)=\frac{P(X\in A,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}$
$P(X\in A|Y\in B)=\frac{P(X\in A,Y\in B)}{P(Y\in B)}$

- What is the difference between these two definitions?
- How can I use them to define the conditional distribution as a measure?

any guidance is appreciated to clear my confusion

Comment: The first form is often used for continuous random variables, where there is a discussion on how to make sense of the expression if $P(Y=y)=0.$ Event $\{Y = y\}$ might be written as something like $Y \in \{y\},$ if $Y$ is a discrete random variable and $P(Y = y) > 0.$ If there are examples following each the two definitions, look at them for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one definition, and the two statements you give are valid.

The conditional probability is defined for two **[events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory))**.

Given a universe of possible outcomes, $\Omega$, a set of events $E$ (actually a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) of events), an event being a subset of $\Omega$, and a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) $P$ on $(\Omega,E)$, with a number of axioms that define a [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) ($(\Omega,E,P)$ is then a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space)), then the [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) of the event $A$ conditioned by the event $B$ such that $P(B)\ne0$ ($A,B\in E$) is:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

---

Note that $X\in A$, $Y=y$, $Y\in B$ are all events. There is a common abuse of notation here. $X$ and $Y$ are [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) (that is, [measurable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) from $\Omega$ to $\Bbb R$), $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Bbb R$, $y$ is a real number, and the preceding events are respectively

- $\{\omega\,|\,\omega\in\Omega\wedge X(\omega)\in A\}$
- $\{\omega\,|\,\omega\in\Omega\wedge Y(\omega)=y\}$
- $\{\omega\,|\,\omega\in\Omega\wedge Y(\omega)\in B\}$

There is no inconsistency here, you just have to be accurate about the notation.

---

The second part of your question: how to define a conditional probability measure?

Given an event $B$ such that $P(B)\ne0$, you can define another probability measure,

$$P_B(A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

You may then check the axioms of a probability on $P_B$ (for instance you have obviously $P_B(\Omega)=\frac{P(\Omega\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B)}{P(B)}=1$). Here you can replace $B$ by any of the preceding events.

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please look at [this]: http://www.gold-saucer.org/math/conditional/conditional.pdf  document , in particular equations 4 and 5 in page 6. This was one of the sources for my confusion. 

How can I define the conditional measure as a push forward measure from the probability space to the Borel space of $\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: See for instance [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_a_random_variable) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation). I gave you the "simpler" definition of a conditional probability, but there are variants. Here, the author is defining the conditional probability with the conditional expectation, which is more general, but also IMO pedagogically debatable, as the conditional expectation is more difficult to grasp.

Comment: so you mean that I can construct a measure from the conditional probability if I fix the event $B$.  One more thing, how can I define the density of the conditional probability?  will it be a function of event $A$ or event $B$ ?

Comment: The conditional probability defined above is not a random variable, it does not have a distribution. But see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution

Comment: If events A and B correspond to events of random variables, would this enable us to define a conditional distribution? if yes, how can I define it?